# Meaning of s_last in D star Lite algorithm

Tags: mobile-robot, control, robotic-arm, motion-planning, algorithm

In the D*Lite algorithm, described in line 21 of Figure 3, on page 4, in [D* Lite](http://idm-lab.org/bib/abstracts/papers/aaai02b.pdf), the `main()` starts with defining $s_{last}=s_{start}$. But value of $s_{last}$ is never updated in the entire algorithm.

So what is the purpose of defining this term and what does it mean?

[image: Pseudo Code from figure 3]

Comment: @BendingUnit22 - I can understand why the OP did not include the pseudo code, as it is not a simple copy and paste job. I have updated the question, with accurate references, a link and a screen shot of the relevant pseudo code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$s_{last}$ *does* change.

Looking at the pseudo code, $s_{last}$ is updated upon *each* iteration of the `while` loop in `main()`, in line 31, $s_{last}=s_{start}$, *if* the condition on line 29 is met:

```
if any edge costs changed
```

Likewise, in figure 4 $s_{last}$ is updated on line 39:

[image: Pseudo Code from figure 4]

Comment: But, before updating the value of $s_{last}$ isn't its value already equal to $s_{start}$ as defined in line 21 of unoptimized version? @Greenonline

Comment: @vacky I knew you would ask that :-) yes, but in line 25 s_start varies... and so s_last varies also. However, I am not giving you a particularly good explanation as to why... I am merely looking at the logic of the pseudo code. Apologies.

Comment: Do you mean in line 26? @Greenonline

Comment: @vacky - Sorry, yes - 26 - Error due to parallax.... :-)